# How to keep my iTunes (app) library after reinstalling Windows?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, windows, migration

I have an iPhone 4 and I'm a windows 7 user; I have the latest iTunes installed on my PC and synchronized with my iPhone; I don't have any music or video in there, as I don't use the iPhone for that purpose, but I have quite a big app library.

If I'm going to reinstall Windows on my computer, or even move to a different one, what should I do to keep my iTunes library? I'm assuming the App Store keeps track of what I've purchased, but how to avoid re-downloading everything again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How to avoid re-downloading everything again?
```

Your apps by default are downloaded to the location 'C:\Users\username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications'. Take a copy of the apps from this location and back it up on an external hard drive, flash drive, DVD or a different machine.

When you re-install or move to a new machine, simply bring the apps back to the new PC and drag-drop them on to the apps section of iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

Just backup your whole iTunes Library folder. On the new OS, install iTunes, copy your Library to the old place and open iTunes holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Mac OS).

A dialog should appear:

[image]

Select `Choose Library...` and select your old Library (I think you have to select the xml-file inside the Library folder) and everything should be as it has been before.

Source: [How to open an alternate iTunes Library file or create a new one](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1589)